# Get location from image in android to php and sometimes error couldn't get location

Tags: php, android, image, gps

I'm using AS
first case : I'm running android app from PC A to device kitkat and marshmallow, then I'm trying to upload image to server and get the location using PHP. the result is when using device kitkat the GPS I can get it, but no in marshmallow

second case : I'm running android app from PC B, to device kitkat and marshmallow, then I'm trying to upload image to server and get the location using PHP. the result is I'm using kitkat and marshmallow the both cannot get GPS from image

third case : I'm running android app from PC B to device kitkat and marshmallow, then I'm trying to upload image to server and get the location using PHP. BUT for now I change the IP to connect server using IP on PC A. the result is when I using device kitkat the GPS I can get it, but using Marshmallow still cannot get the location

in code I have already using android runtime permission. there's no logcat error
how I can fix that?

and this code PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$latitude = 0;
$longitude = 0;

$lokasi = "uploads/";
$file_name      = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_ext       = explode('.',$file_name);
$file_ext       = strtolower(end($file_ext));
$file_size      = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp       = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$filename       = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$target_path    = $lokasi . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
echo basename($_FILES['image']['name'])."<BR>";
//get latitude and longitude
$image_file = $file_tmp;
echo "string : ".$image_file;
if(file_exists($image_file)){
    $details = exif_read_data($image_file); 
    $sections = explode(',',$details['SectionsFound']); 

    if(in_array('GPS',array_flip($sections))){ 

        echo $latitude = number_format(format_gps_data($details['GPSLatitude'],$details['GPSLatitudeRef']),10, ',', ' '); 
        $longitude = number_format(format_gps_data($details['GPSLongitude'],$details['GPSLongitudeRef']),10, ',', ' '); 
    }
    else{
        die('GPS data not found'); 
    }
}
else{
    die('File does not exists'); 
}

function format_gps_data($gpsdata,$lat_lon_ref){
    $gps_info = array();
    foreach($gpsdata as $gps){
        list($j , $k) = explode('/', $gps);
        array_push($gps_info,$j/$k);
    }
    $coordination = $gps_info[0] + ($gps_info[1]/60.00) + ($gps_info[2]/3600.00);
    return (($lat_lon_ref == "S" || $lat_lon_ref == "W" ) ? '-'.$coordination : $coordination).' '.$lat_lon_ref;
}
///////////////////////////////

$nama_file = $latitude . "_" . $longitude . "." . $file_ext;
$target_path=$lokasi . $nama_file;


try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file
    if (!move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_path)) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    }

    echo "Success";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

and this code for upload image

```
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Making progress bar visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // updating progress bar value
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

            // updating percentage value
            txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                image = new FileBody(sourceFile);
                // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
                entity.addPart("website",
                        new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
                entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

            // showing the server response in an alert dialog
            showAlert(result);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That is a ridiculous amount of code you dropped here. You are suposed to post only relevant code. Only the upload code would do. Why bother us with camera, permissions and database? Please remove all that stuff.

Comment: @greenapps because first the app open camera but for open camera must have permission then image can upload..

Comment: We all know that. And it has nothing to do with your problem. So please start the garbage collector.

Comment: @greenapps like this? I think the php code will useful.. and how I can fix my problem?

Comment: Ok. That was a start. But why a complete activity with onCreate, that preview? That database insert? All irrelevant. Drop it all please. Only the upload asynctask will do. You are supposed to post a MINIMAL example. Php is usefull indeed. If you c!ean up then we can start helping you.

Comment: @greenapps oke done

Comment: Ok. Now which echo's do you get back from php when things go wrong? And how often does that happen? Exact figures pleass.

Comment: @greenapps that will show `echo "Success";` because image success upload, but gps will show `0.0000000000`.. it's always like this if the statement in my post (first until third case) are met

Comment: Who is showing that? Which gps? Unclear. And why do not you see/report t `echo $latitude = number_format....` ?

Comment: You should get back too `echo "string : ".$image_file;`.

Comment: @greenapps php send `Success` to android and that showing to user.. GPS I mean is latitude and longitude from image.. `echo $latitude = ....` that showing `0.0000000000`

Comment: @greenapps `echo "string : ".$image_file;` showing the temporary file of image

Comment: I asked you what you got back from php and you only mentioned "Succes". And now bit by bit you happen to get more back. Why didnt you tell when asked? In this way it is difficult helping you. And you still did not answer all my questions.